# Drawing irregular shapes in iOS

Tags: ios, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, quartz-core

I need to draw like the one in the below image as one touch and drags across the screen.
[image]

First I tried it using cocos2d to get like this but, couldn't get it exactly like the above image, i.e I could get only like the below image only.

[image]

The cocos2d code in brief is depicted in [one of my previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949104/sharp-edged-sprites) where I couldn't get any help. Now Im trying to do this done in `QuartzCore` framework. I surfed for a whole day, but couldn't get any relevant solutions for it.

Now, my question is, how I can draw like the first image using `QuartzCore` framework? Else, is there any other frameworks or ways to do it? 
Can someone help me?